# Best practices for handling math calculations in a flash project?

Tags: flash, actionscript, oop

I'm building a Flash project where it needs to handle some math, like an acceleration formula. My director has recommended a design pattern where I include the calculations directly in the flash object, but that doesn't seem like it's very good OOP.

What's the best practice for calculations in Flash? Should it be a separate object, so I can keep the "non-Flash" parts together and out of the way? What are people's experiences with including it inline vs. keeping it separate?

Comment: Is there a technical question in there somewhere?

Comment: Programming's not all about coding. Design patterns, project planning, architecture are important too. This is not meant to be some watered down question for 'Startups'.

Comment: Do you mind if I rephrase your question to actually make it a question? Right now, it seems more like a rant, but I think there's a legitimate design question in there.

Comment: Please rephrase. I'm not really asking about parsing engines either, so I'd appreciate your help:)

Comment: I took my best shot at it, though not much of your original text is left. If I've missed what you're asking, please roll it back or edit it again.

Comment: Thanks. Much better than what I could ask:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the contrary.

A flash object which accelerates should have its motion equations implemented in flash.
It should have a class handling it, encapsulating the math. This way, it isn't stuck there, it is just in the right place.

If you take the math out of flash, you'll have to update the objects' positions by yourself, thus loosing a lot of flash's abilities.

Comment: Encapsulation's a good idea. What do you think of a XML parser that processes the math?

Comment: An XML parser to do all the math sounds like over-engineering to me, and introduces a pretty big weak point in your app. Just put your equations in a class and load that class up when you need to use it.  If you want it to be dynamic without recompiling, hold config vars in xml (like, gravity, velocity, friction, etc) and just load those up and pass them to the equation.